# Make Ubuntu 12.04 to remember its last session

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

When I login to ubuntu 12.04 it should run all applications automatically which I have run during the last login. In 10.04 version there was an option for this. In the latest version how to do this?

Comment: The answers in this question on askubuntu are helpful in this matter: http://askubuntu.com/questions/8834/how-do-i-save-remember-last-used-window-position-and-size-for-applications

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is hibernation :-
try if this solves your issue

https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation